# Wrong PDF bookmark hierarchy when using Parts (KOMA-script)

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, koma-script, bookmarks

I want the Index and the Bibliography to appear in the Table of Contents and in the PDF bookmarks. However, the default hierachy for them is "chapter", which usually isn't a problem, but this time it messes things up.

The index appears as a chapter from "Part 2" in my MWE but I want it to have the same hierarchy as the "Preface". (I have the same issue with the bibliography)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{index=totoc,toc=index}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    hidelinks,
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\chapter{Preface}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\part{First Part}
\chapter{A Chapter}
Hello \index{Hello}

\part{Last Part}
\chapter{Another Chapter}

\backmatter

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: How the ToC looks]

[image: How the bookmarks look]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current version of the KOMA classes load the `bookmark` package and with it you can reset the bookmarklevel:

```
\backmatter
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}

\printindex
```

[image]

Comment: This is almost what I want but I'm ok with that. The problem persists in the ToC. The spacing makes it look like the Index is a chapter of the last part.

Comment: You can always add some space in the toc, e.g. with `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\medskip}`